# # selector with id including ':'

Tags: html, dom

I read that the character '`:`' is a valid character in the `id` attribute.
I assign a id that includes a '`:`'. For instance `id="n:1"`.

However when using `document.querySelector("#n:1")` a DOM-exception is raised (in Chrome).

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, [the HTML5.1 specification states](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-id-attribute):

> 3.2.5.1 The `id` attribute
>
> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

So you need to escape characters in the selector sequence, I'm assuming you use CSS' rules for escaping characters, but they're complicated:

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

In short, if you don't need to support IE8 or older, use a backslash - but you **also need to escape that backslash in JavaScript** (so the CSS selector parser sees the backslash), so you need to double-escape them.

So try this:

```
querySelectorAll('#n\\:1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the colon with two backslashes:

```
document.querySelector("#n\\:1")
```

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> To match ID or selectors that do not follow the CSS syntax (by using a
>   colon or space inappropriately for example), you must escape the
>   character with a back slash. As the backslash is an escape character
>   in JavaScript, if you are entering a literal string, you must escape
>   it twice (once for the JavaScript string, and another time for
>   querySelector)